# Use a different error message when making a request in Loopback app

Tags: node.js, error-handling, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm working on an application in Loopback 3. My app is making a post request to another service outside of my application.

```
    Model.prototype.doSomething() = async()=>{
   ...
      let res = await request.post(that service api).send(...);
      someOtherThing.param = res.something;
   ...
   return someOtherThing;

}
```

When that service fails, it sends a status code and an error message. Example: `{"error":{"statusCode":422,"name":"Error","message":"Parameters are out of range.","status":422}}`.

But as soon as this gets to loopback, it just completely forgets about this error message and it returns: `{"error":{"statusCode":422,"name":"Error","message":"Unprocessable Entity"}}` Before I could actually handle this myself. How do I go about changing that message that my application returns. It can either be the same as the message from the service or something that I'd be able to specify myself.

Answer (score 0):

A try catch block. I am like this sometimes.